# Microsoft bot framework v3 webchat channel not working with ngrok

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I created chatbot with microsoft bot framework v3.
I use mssql server 2017 database.
It runs perfectly on emulator. After that I registered my chatbot on azure through Bot channel registration.
Then I save AppId and Password etc in web.config and also in emulator and tested, It runs without any error.
I use ngrok , as ngrok http 3979 it gives me https://........ngrok.io and I save that access point in azure bot reg endpoint with api/messages.
Then I get embed code with key and placed in page.html and when I send message it gives me error as:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey are you developing in C# or node.js? What is page.html? How are you embedding webchat in the Webpage? Using IFrame or adding the javascript code?

Comment: I'm developing with c# and I embedded IFram in web page of django app running on localhost:8000, I didn't add Javascript code.

Comment: What key are you using? I suppose you are using key from Webchat section, and not from Directline section. when something like this, its very likely that there will be some logs in the console of web page. Can you show what logs are you getting in the web page's console.

Comment: I attached the screenshots and in azure webchat channel issues are:
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code BadGateway

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm using webchat and here the screenshots

[webconfig and running emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei0la.png)

[ngrok http 3979 and also save it azure settings as endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhTF.png)

[When run django app, say hi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjIXu.png)

Comment: Hi Muhammad! Can you post what's showing in the Developer Console when you try to send a message to the bot through ngrok? Like, what shows when you get the response in the third picture you posted above?